# Why have a stainless steel griddle instead of simply a stainless steel pan?

Tags: cookware

I've seen a lot of gas cooktops that have stainless steel griddles built into them. This seemed like a useful feature, but it occurred to me that I could just throw on a stainless steel pan, presumably to the same effect.

Are there any advantages to having a stainless steel griddle like this vs. a good stainless steel pan?

Comment: Stainless? Really? Mine has a griddle and grill but they aren't stainless steel.

Comment: @Catija I've also seen iron ones etc... I suppose the question remains. Why have a griddle instead of just a large pan? Seems like a pan is cheaper, easier to clean, and more versatile.

Answer (score 4):

A built-in griddle has much more area to work with, and is stationary relative to the cooktop, so wouldn't shift when you move food around on it.

Comment: 1. The griddles that I've seen for home use don't seem to have more surface area than a standard large stainless pan. 2. Perhaps the answer is opinion based in the end, and if that is the case that is a good answer for me to know! I thought perhaps there was an important or interesting difference that was relevant.

Answer (score 1):

A griddle's low sides make it easier to flip large and/or delicate things.

I have not seen the cooktops you speak of, but I lived in a rental with a very huge old gas cooker that had a cast aluminum griddle in the center. It was bigger than the cast iron one my mom's got which covers two burners. A big griddle is pretty fun to have and very handy if you're making breakfast for a crowd, so it's no surprise that a high-end-ish cooker might have one.

tl;dr: Those are for people who really like pancakes.